# The line color of zedgraph control in c#.net changes as the background color. How to set it a fix color?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am generating the graph at runtime using zedgraph control. The graph is generated but the line color of zedgraph control changes as the background color. I want to set the same color that was set at design time. How to set fix color to line? I am using the code to give color as :

```
refLine = gp.AddCurve("", null, null, Color.Green , SymbolType.None);
```

at the load event of form. But it gets changed automatically.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried in an [edit].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
refLine = gp.AddCurve("", null, null, Color.Green , SymbolType.None);
```

Which returns a `LineItem`. There are at least two different color properties. Above you set the `LineItem.Color` property. Try after to set this :

```
refLine.Line.Fill.Color = Color.Green;
zgc.Refresh();  //not sure if needed
```

Can't remember what the `LineItem.Color` property is, but it may be a fill color for other views than line chart, for example bar or candlestick charts.

Also, due to the complexity of Zedgraph, be sure to use [good documentation.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20documentation/5.1.0%20%2B%204.6.0/)